# Add ThirdPartySettings to individual paragraphs of a certain bundle?

Tags: 8, entities, paragraphs

I want to add configuration settings to Paragraph entities in a specific bundle in Drupal 8. Theres potentially a lot of options and the need to change/update them over time, so I figure the best way is through ThirdPartySettings and not adding more fields to it. I am going to use these values to influence certain aspects of the render and for search queries.

I can see where you can add settings to the bundle itself, but how do you provide them for each paragraph instance on a node via a config schema?

I see this in the Paragraphs config schema dir:

```
paragraphs.paragraphs_type.*:
  type: config_entity
  label: 'Paragraphs type config'
  mapping:
    .....
```

But `paragraphs.paragraphs_type.*.third_party.foo...` would add it to the bundle, right?

Comment: Yes, it's like Layout Builder stores per-view-mode settings as third party config and per-node-settings as field content. What you are trying to do is the same for Paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A paragraph is a content entity, which doesn't support third party settings. Third party settings are just for config entities.

The solution is just to use fields, awkward as it might seem.

Comment: Ah damn. It would be nice in this case to avoid fields, +2 tables, etc. I guess its the only route for now.

Comment: Yeah, feel your pain, I was in a similar position a couple of months back but with Layout Canvases